# calculated column stops working when exdternal filter used

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some Fact Revenue, I am trying to group by Conca, and display the values only if negative…

For doing it I have this calculated column:

```
=
VAR name1 = Revenue[Conca]

VAR name2=

    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Revenue[CostOfQuality] ),
         FILTER ( Revenue, Revenue[Conca] = name1  )
    )

RETURN
if (name2>0, 0, Revenue[CostOfQuality])
```

It works:

[image]

(highest value is 0 as expected):

Now...

If I drag **fiscal year** it stops working:
[image]

Why is it that I see numbers higher than 0?? (I want it to still work even if I bring other filters...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a calculated column is computed computed once on the whole dataset after the data are loaded, and is basically a "static column".

Whatever the expected result, you are looking for a measure, which gets computed in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Calculated columns and calculated tables are different from measures, since they are static: You can filter them, but they don't recalculate on filter changes.